# Recvfrom : using stack as buffer (len:4096)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm using recvfrom syscall with a lenght of 0x1000. If I use a buffer from .bss there's no problem; recvfrom waits for client data.

```
buffer: resb 4096
```

But if I use a pointer to the stack as buffer, mov a qword at the address, it's doesn't fit the 4096 bytes and recvfrom doesn't wait !

What I understand is the stack isn't initialized to 0 for the 4096 bytes and assumes data is in.

Moreover, If I reduce my length sent to recvfrom to 0x10 i.e, since qword fit in, recvfrom waits for client input.

Do I need to initialize the stack to 0 for 4096 bytes downward ?

Thank you for your attention.

code :

```
mov rdi, [server_fd]
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdx, rdx
mov rax, SYS_ACCEPT
syscall


mov [clients_fd], rax ;store the clients_fd

mov rdi, rax ; mov client socket fd to rdi
mov rsi, rsp ; use stack as buffer 
mov qword [rsi], 0
mov rdx, BUFFER_SIZE; 0x1000
xor rcx, rcx
xor r10, r10 ; flags
xor r9, r9
xor r8, r8
mov rax, SYS_RECVFROM
syscall

mov rdi, [clients_fd]; restore client_fd 
mov rsi, rsp; buffer address 
xor r10, r10
call _strlen; returns str len in rax
mov rdx, rax ; rax contains the string len
mov rax, SYS_SENDTO
syscall

call sys_close

xor rdi, rdi
call sys_exit
```

Comment: Please add the relevant lines of code.

Comment: Where do you allocate space on the stack though?

Comment: The call to `strlen` will use the stack, likely disturbing your data. Any interrupt happening during the processing will also use some stack space.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to allocate memory, I edited my initial post with the correction

Comment: Post answers as answers, not edits that make the question a non-question.  Note that the red zone in the x86-64 SysV ABI does make the first 128B below rsp safe from asynchronous modification, so you can use it without modifying `rsp`.  (@Bo: this is user-space code.  Interrupts don't use the user-space stack, for security reasons.  But yes, synchronously clobbering it with `strlen` is bad.  Without any signal handlers, there might not be anything that asynchronously clobbers beyond the red zone, but even things like debuggers might do so.)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not just `strlen`, it's not entirely clear you can use the red zone across a system call, which is also synchronous. In theory it should work because of the stack switching, but it's not guaranteed by the ABI.

Comment: @RossRidge: hmm, interesting point.  I should raise an issue on the ABI's github page to request clarification.  I assume that it's 100% safe in the current version of Linux, but maybe not a good idea if the ABI doesn't guarantee it.  IIRC, Linux doesn't touch user-space memory at all in the `syscall` entry / return code, and I assume it doesn't anywhere else.

Comment: @RossRidge: [github issue](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/issues/3).  IDK if that gets much attention, though, since most discussion happens on the google group.  (links on [this wiki page](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all, it was as easy as @Michael noted, here's the solution:

```
I had to reserv 0x1000 bytes on the stack
```

code:

```
mov rdi, [server_fd]
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdx, rdx
mov rax, SYS_ACCEPT
syscall


mov [clients_fd], rax ;store the clients_fd

mov rdi, rax ; mov client socket fd to rdi
sub rsp, BUFFER_SIZE
mov rsi, rsp
mov qword [rsi], 0
mov rdx, BUFFER_SIZE; 0x1000
xor rcx, rcx
xor r10, r10 ; flags
xor r9, r9
xor r8, r8
mov rax, SYS_RECVFROM
syscall

mov rdi, [clients_fd]; restore client_fd 
mov rsi, rsp; buffer address 
xor r10, r10
call _strlen; returns str len in rax
mov rdx, rax ; rax contains the string len
mov rax, SYS_SENDTO
syscall

call sys_close

xor rdi, rdi
call sys_exit
```

Yesterday I did error catching and standard errno messages display.
Thanks everyone for the help !